# Module composition with for_each conditional

Tags: azure, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

On my root module, I am declaring two modules (paired_regions_network and paired_regions_app), that both iterate a set of regions.

```
module "paired_regions_network" {
  source                  = "./modules/network"
  application_hostname    = ["${module.paired_regions_app.website_hostname}"]  // THIS IS BREAKING THE CODE
  ...
  for_each = (var.environment == "TEST" || var.environment == "PROD") ? var.paired_regions : { region1 = var.paired_regions.region1 }
}

module "paired_regions_app" {
  source                  = "./modules/multi-region"
  ...
  for_each = (var.environment == "TEST" || var.environment == "PROD") ? var.paired_regions : { region1 = var.paired_regions.region1 }
}

output "network_outputs" {
  value = module.paired_regions_network
}

output "app_outputs" {
  value = module.paired_regions_app
}
```

The iterated regions are declared as follows:

```
variable "paired_regions" {
  description = "The paired regions"
  default = { 
    region1 = { 
      ...
    },
    region2 = { 
      ...
    }
  }
}
```

From the `paired_regions_network` module I want to have access to the output coming from the `paired_regions_app` module, namely the `website_hostname` value, which I want to assign to the `application_hostname` parameter, of the `paired_regions_network` module, as shown above.

```
output "website_hostname" {
  value       = azurerm_app_service.was_app.default_site_hostname
  description = "The hostname of the website"
}
```

How can I change the line below, so that I am able to access the outputted website hostname by the other module?

```
  application_hostname    = ["${module.paired_regions_app.website_hostname}"]
```

With the above code, I am getting this error:

```
│ Error: Unsupported attribute
│
│   on main.tf line 24, in module "paired_regions_network":
│   24:   application_hostname    = ["${module.paired_regions_app.website_hostname}"]
│     ├────────────────
│     │ module.paired_regions_app is object with 2 attributes
│
│ This object does not have an attribute named "website_hostname".
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using `for_each` in `paired_regions_app` you have to access its outputs by key.

```
application_hostname    = [module.paired_regions_app[each.key].website_hostname]
```

Comment: Damn, I have been stuck here for hours, and you figure this out in a couple of minutes :O

It indeed worked, but without the square brackets! Thank you so much!

Comment: @ccoutinho No problem. Glad it worked out:-)

Comment: what if I would also need to access some output from paired_regions_network, on paired_regions_app @Marcin? Is this possible to do, without getting a Cycle error?

Comment: @ccoutinho I'm not sure what do you mean? Maybe new question would be better with new error messages and explanation.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68738008/module-composition-between-two-modules-using-a-conditional-for-each-on-both-ways