# Module composition between two modules using a conditional for_each on both ways

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure

On my root module, I am declaring two modules (paired_regions_network and paired_regions_app), that both iterate a set of regions.

```
module "paired_regions_network" {
  source                  = "./modules/network"
  application_hostname    = module.paired_regions_app[each.key].website_hostname
  ...
  for_each = ( var.environment == "TEST" || var.environment == "PROD") ? { region1 = var.paired_regions.region1 } : {  }
}

module "paired_regions_app" {
  source                  = "./modules/multi-region"
  wag_public_ip           = module.paired_regions_network[each.key].wag_public_ip
  ...
  for_each = (var.environment == "TEST" || var.environment == "PROD") ? var.paired_regions : { region1 = var.paired_regions.region1 }
}

output "network_outputs" {
  value = module.paired_regions_network
}

output "app_outputs" {
  value = module.paired_regions_app
}
```

The iterated regions are declared as follows:

```
variable "paired_regions" {
  description = "The paired regions"
  default = { 
    region1 = { 
      ...
    },
    region2 = { 
      ...
    }
  }
}
```

From the `paired_regions_network` module I want to have access to the output coming from the `paired_regions_app` module, namely the `website_hostname` value, which I want to assign to the `application_hostname` parameter, of the `paired_regions_network` module, as shown above.

```
output "website_hostname" {
  value       = azurerm_app_service.was_app.default_site_hostname
  description = "The hostname of the website"
}
```

And from the `paired_regions_app` module I want to have access to the output coming from the `paired_regions_network` module, namely the `wag_public_ip` value, which I want to assign to the parameter with the same name, of the `paired_regions_app` module, as shown above.

```
output "wag_ip_address" {
  value       = azurerm_public_ip.network_ip.ip_address
  description = "The Public IP address that will be used by the app gateway"
}
```

But this causes a dependency cycle, that I can't get rid off. The error is the following:

> Error: Cycle: ...

Can I pass the output between the two modules, without causing the dependency cycle?

Comment: I don't think you can do this. You need to extract the troublesome part, and create third module.

Comment: that did the trick! Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per @Marcin's advice, I was able to overcome the issue by creating a third module containing only the Public IP resource. So, the `paired_regions_app` module would depend on the new module instead of depending on the `paired_regions_network` module. The `paired_regions_network` would then depend on both the other two modules. Besides removing the output from the `paired_regions_network` module, the code changes are as follows:

**Root Module**

```
module "paired_regions_ips" {
  source                  = "./modules/public-ip"
  ...
  for_each = ( var.environment == "TEST" || var.environment == "PROD") ? { region1 = var.paired_regions.region1 } : {  }
}

module "paired_regions_app" {
  source                  = "./modules/multi-region"
  wag_public_ip           = length(module.paired_regions_ips) > 0 ? (lookup(module.paired_regions_ips, each.key, "") != "" ? join("/", ["${module.paired_regions_ips[each.key].ip_obj.ip_address}", "32"]) : "" ) : ""
  ...
  for_each = (var.environment == "TEST" || var.environment == "PROD") ? var.paired_regions : { region1 = var.paired_regions.region1 }
}

module "paired_regions_network" {
  source                  = "./modules/network"
  wag_public_ip_id        = module.paired_regions_ips[each.key].ip_obj.id
  application_hostname    = module.paired_regions_app[each.key].website_hostname
  ...
  for_each = ( var.environment == "TEST" || var.environment == "PROD") ? { region1 = var.paired_regions.region1 } : {  }
}

output "network_outputs" {
  value = module.paired_regions_ips
}

output "app_outputs" {
  value = module.paired_regions_app
}
```

**The new module**

```
output "ip_obj" {
  value       = azurerm_public_ip.network_ip
  description = "The Public IP address"
}
```

---

**Some remarks:**

- Because the `paired_regions_ips` module has different conditions on the `for_each` loop when compared to the `paired_regions_app` module, I had to add some logic when fetching the output from the latter
- The new module outputs a public IP object, so that I have access to both its ID (from the `paired_regions_network` module) and to the IP address (from the `paired_regions_app` module)